# How to write this code with single expression definition but to keep expression bodied definition of entire function in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming

```
void Foo(int a, int b)
=> Bar(a + 1, b + 1)
```

This can be written like this to make single definition of Inc

```
void Foo(int a, int b)
{
    Func<int, int> Inc = (x) => x + 1;
    Bar(Inc(a), Inc(b));
}
```

I am looking for elegant way to keep expression bodied definition of Foo, but have only one lambda to define Inc expression. It is easy if I make Inc as separated function, but i am interested to keep it as lambda.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Expression bodied members can only use a *statement*, not a block.

Comment: `void Foo(int a, int b) => Bar(++a, ++b)`? In the general case you can't, only *statements* are allowed.

Comment: It is possible, check my answer. Not that 'x + 1' is only simplified example, this expression can be very big, so it is important to have only one definition of it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will work, but downside is that it must be written for each number of parameters, but as Func<> is defined in similar fashion it is not so bad.

```
public static class FunctionalExtensions
{
    public static Action<A, A> ArgumentTransform<A>(this Func<A, A> argConverter, Action<A, A> action)
        => (x, y) => action(argConverter(x), argConverter(y));

    public static Func<A, A, R> ArgumentTransform<A, R>(this Func<A, A> argConverter, Func<A, A, R> function)
        => (x, y) => function(argConverter(x), argConverter(y));
}
```

it can be used like this:

```
void Foo(int a, int b) => new Func<int, int>((x) => x + 1).ArgumentTransform(Bar)(a, b);
```

Comment: The whole point of expression bodied members is to make things more compact and readable. Are you seriously considering this approach? Just for the sake of using expression bodied members? You are "drowning" the original method signature with additional information that has very little semantic value; in your example `argConverter` could be defined inside the method itself (´Func<int, int> Inc = (x) => x + 1;´), why put the burden on the callsites?

Comment: Second, do not answer your own question. If you have additional information, simply edit your question.

Comment: I think you got this wrong, if it is not meant to answer question if  answer is found, then why it is this option not blocked? And sorry, down-voting question and answer just because you gave wrong answer is silly and sad @InBetween.

Comment: I can post a question about my grandmother's arthritis? If its wrong how come its not blocked? If you know the answer to your own question then why are you asking it in the first place?

Comment: Omg i found it while you were busy giving incorrect answers, check the times, and I did't wan't to delete it because I think this is cool question and usage is cool.

Comment: Third: The downvote is because your question as it stands, and above all your answer make no sense and it is, IMO (I'm allowed to have one, right?), an antipattern. Overcomplicating code for the sake of leveraging a fancy new language feature is in my book wrong.

Comment: One day, you will learn what is functional programming and maybe you will not think the same... Until then, good bye!

Comment: I know what functional programming is, thank you very much. If your question had pointed out that `argConverter` were to be defined at the callsite, then your answer makes sense. But the truth is that in your barebones repro, `argConverter` is defined *inside* `Foo(,)`. So good luck explaining how functional programming has to do with anything here, and most of all with expression bodied statements that are simply compiler syntactic sugar, not a new functional programming feature in C#. Have a nice day.

Comment: @InBetween It is specifically OK to answer your own question on SO. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer